# Azure DevOps: 'Replace Tokens task' having problem setting variable files from JSON

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to setup a '**Replace Tokens Task**' for my build pipeline from a JSON file that will hold environmental variables as follow:

[image]

And then my JSON environment file:

[image]

The JavaScript target file to replace the tokens in:

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please don't embed images of code and error messages, unless there's some aspect of them that can't be conveyed by text. Can you edit your question to place the file references inline as text? Not only does this make it easier for people to read, but it also improves search engine indexing so that users with similar problems can find this question.

Comment: Hi yishaihl, does this issue persist to block you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

[image]

I can reproduce same issue on my side, and I think it only indicates there's something wrong with your `Variable files(JSON)` input:

[image]

Please make sure the variables are **successfully** loaded from the variable json file.

1.Make sure your `env-config.json` file has content below:

```
{
    "alambda.endpoint":"ForTest"
}
```

2.Check carefully about the path of your `env-config.json` file! (In my opinion, your issue is more like a **path issue**~) If the task can't find and load the file, it also throws `variable not found`. For this:

- Make sure the relative path is correct.
- Try cut the long path, I'm not sure if the issue results from the too long path. Try using `**/env-config.json` instead of the very long path.
- If above tips can't work, I suggest you can move the `env-config.json` file to root folder `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` with [Copy Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) or what.   (About `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables)). Then try it again with `**/env-config.json`.

Comment: @yishaihl You're welcome~ Do you mind [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) since it's helpful? So that other members with similar issue can easily find the useful info from accepted answer and we can archive this thread for you. Have a nice day!